# How to update files in a github branch with another branch?

Tags: git, github

I am working with github, but unable to figure out how to update a branch with another branch changes,

I have a github branch called `develop`, after that I have created another branch called `release/v1` from develop branch.

Now after few days I have checkout the `develop` branch again and made few commits to fix few issues, now I want to push the new changes in develop branch into `release/v1` branch. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is merge develop into release/v1. To do this, check out release/v1

```
git checkout release/v1
```

then merge in develop

```
git merge develop
```

Comment: assuming the remote is set up already, the command is `git push`. If the remote branch is not set up, try `git push -u origin release/v1`